# Salesforce1 APK

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

Does Salesforce offer their Salesforce1 APK for developers to download? It seems like the only places I can find it are third-party websites and I would be much more comfortable downloading it from Salesforce itself.

Comment: Um, what? Why not get it from the Play store? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salesforce.chatter

Comment: I want the APK so that I can add it to my Android emulator to test how my app will emulate. I personally do not have an android device so I cannot download it from the google store

Comment: Looks like you might have some luck with a Chrome extension. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/how-can-i-download-an-apk-file-from-the-play-store

Answer (score 3):

Officially, most vendors do NOT provide APKs directly. But unofficially, there are multiple ways to get it :)

A) You can actually get a Android Simulator VM (plenty of such options on the Internet) which runs Google Play and then download the app that you need

B) You could use the plugin quoted on this [thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/how-can-i-download-an-apk-file-from-the-play-store) to pull the APK down from Google Play

Having said that, it's still recommended to be using the official APK on a device.